# web services for win 8 phone app development

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8, odata

I am looking for a library for odata services. Is there even such a thing?

Like if I want to develop an app for craigslist and I want to know what services are available to out there, to check that is there a standard library service where I can check what is available

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to start with www.odata.org. this one is realy good to start on odata.

check the Ecosystem under odata.org site here will find alots of sample and apps.

http://www.odata.org/ecosystem/